# Convert Image from Request to Pygame Surface

Tags: python, pygame, python-requests

I want to get an image from a url and convert it to a Pygame surface to display.

```
import pygame, requests

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

#I'll use the python logo as an example
url = "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png"

img_data = requests.get(url).content
```

What command do I use to convert received data (bytes) to a pygame surface to display to the pygame window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load your image into a file-like object where you can use pygame to read it:

```py
import pygame, requests
import pygame.image
import io

.
.
.

r = requests.get(url)
img = io.BytesIO(r.content)

pygame.image.load(img, namehint="") # -> Surface
```